# Composer require runs out of memory. PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, voyager

**Hi, I am trying solve some problem when I am install voyager.
When I try to run composer require I am getting the out of memory error. I am not understand what exably happend. Its result on my console:**

> > > @DESKTOP->>>>> /c/xampp/htdocs/ (master)
> > > $ composer require tcg/voyager
> > > Using version ^1.4 for tcg/voyager
> > > ./composer.json has been updated
> > > Loading composer repositories with package information
> > > Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> > > PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 83```

**Maybe there's a problem with the composer.JSON, something I need to check out. What you should pay attention to what is the problem**
My composer.json file```
{

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "convertapi/convertapi-php": "^1.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "openpayu/openpayu": "^2.2",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.14",
    "pragmarx/tracker": "^3.5",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.8",
    "spatie/pdf-to-image": "^2.0",
    "tcg/voyager": "^1.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
    "tanmuhittin/laravel-google-translate": "^1.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/HelperFunctions.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"repositories": {
    "hooks": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://larapack.io"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using xampp.
you can try to change the `memory_limit` in `php.ini`.
[image]

Find this:

```php
;memory_limit=512M
```

Change to :

```php
memory_limit =-1
```

Then restart the Apache from xampp

Comment: Why  this problem is also present when I am trying to upload a project to the server?

Comment: @Inna because the one I show you is for your local development when you upload to server it's a different environment, it's a different question. You need to change the memory_limit on your server.

Comment: @Inna my answer is correct why un-accept my answer.?

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the voyager into your server using this command:
`COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require tcg/voyager`

instead of just `composer require tcg/voyager`

I found this on this [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/allowed-memory-size-of-1610612736-bytes-exhausted). Hope it helps. Andy Song solution is better though.

Answer (score 0):

If your composer is in /usr/local/bin/ use:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer require tcg/voyager
```

--

refer to composer document https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

To get the current memory_limit value, run:

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

Try increasing the limit in your php.ini file (ex. /etc/php5/cli/php.ini for Debian-like systems):

; Use -1 for unlimited or define an explicit value like 2G

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Composer also respects a memory limit defined by the COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT environment variable:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer.phar <...>
```

Or, you can increase the limit with a command-line argument:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar <...>
```